# How to set NGINX to forward by header(s)?

Tags: nginx

How to detect (a) specific header(s) in a request and then forward the request based on the said header(s)?

Let's say I have a request's header has:

`X-Application: 'eCommerce'`

and then I want to forward it to `127.0.0.1:3000` while keeping all other traffic to `127.0.0.1:8000`.

Answer (score 1):

The value of any HTTP header is available via the [`$http_<header>`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_http_) nginx variable. I think the easiest way to solve this is to use [`map`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html#map) block:

```
map $http_x_application $backend {
    eCommerce    127.0.0.1:3000;
    default      127.0.0.1:8000;
}
```

and then use your `proxy_pass` directive in a following way:

```
proxy_pass http://$backend;
```

Please note that the `map` block should be defined in the `http` context outside the `server` block.